Get response headers from Spring Boot GraphQlClient (HttpSyncGraphQlClient) request
I have a Java 21 Spring Boot 3.3.2 application that uses MVC. I use spring-boot-starter-graphql and they recently released an HttpSyncGraphQlClient (blocking) to send GraphQL requests.
When I send the request and receive a response, I do not see any option in the response to get response headers.
private HttpSyncGraphQlClient refreshGraphQlClient(String url) {
    return graphQlClient.mutate().url(url).headers(httpHeaders -> httpHeaders.addAll(requestContext.getRequestHeaders())).build();
}

public <T> T sendGraphQlRequest(String url, String requestName, Map<String, Object> variables, ParameterizedTypeReference<T> responseType) {
    var response = refreshGraphQlClient(url)
            .documentName(requestName)
            .variables(variables)
            .retrieveSync(requestName)
            .toEntity(responseType);

    logger.info("GraphQL request response: {}", response);
    return response;
}

Sending the requests works fine, and I am able to retrieve my expected results. However, I cannot find anywhere that I can get the response headers. The .retrieveSync(String path) returns GraphQlClient.RetrieveSyncSpec, but I do not see anything in the GraphQlClient that returns headers. The .toEntity() returns <D> D.
I also use RestClient (which my HttpSyncGraphQlClient uses), and when I send requests using the RestClient (not my HttpSyncGraphQlClient), I am able to get response headers after calling .toEntity() because it returns a <T> ResponseEntity<T>, and then I get the response headers from that.
Is there no way to get response headers from HttpSyncGraphQlClient?
